# Rounded image without resizing/cropping/stretching

Tags: html, image, css, alignment

I'm trying to create an simple div that will contain images which can have different sizes and scales.
The image should not be stretched or cropped and must be centered vertically and horizontally.

Currently I'm stuck with this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLfxb3nh/)

```
.circleImage {    
    height: 100px;      /* equals max image height */
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;    
    text-align: center;   
    line-height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: solid 1px grey;
}

.circleImage img{
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

There are those tiny spaces at the top of the second and third image. Any ideas how I can get rid of them?

[image: Zoomed screenshot]

Comment: can't work on jsfiddle. Images broken

Comment: @Tushar Don't know what you mean. For me it's working as expected on jsfiddle

Comment: Maybe, `vertical-align: top;` for images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/k7fpz8be/

```
<div class="circleImage">
    <span class="helper"></span><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt"logo" title="landscape" />
</div>
<br />
<div class="circleImage">
    <span class="helper"></span><img src="https://placehold.it/350x350" alt"logo" title="square" />
</div>
<br />
<div class="circleImage">
    <span class="helper"></span><img src="https://placehold.it/150x350" alt"logo" title="portrait" />
</div>


.circleImage {
    height: 100px;      /* equals max image height */
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius:50px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.helper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.circleImage img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

This should works

Answer (score 0):

Set the image as div background as below,

```
<div class="circleImage"   style="background: url('https://placehold.it/350x350');  background-size: cover;">
```

Now the image is perfectly fit within the div.

Comment: For this I need to change the style-property of the `div`-element for each image. I just need a wrapper for my `img`-tag

Answer (score 0):

Increase the `width` and `height` on `.circleImage img` to 105%.

http://jsfiddle.net/qLfxb3nh/2/